# set selected item in combobox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, combobox, selecteditem

I am using this code to add a value to a combobox different then the one displayed: [how to add value to combobox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887388/how-to-add-value-to-combobox-item)

Lets suppose i have 3 values in my Combobox:

```
 item 1
 item 2
 item 3
```

If i chose `item 2` from the dropdown the code in the link works. But if i TYPE `item 2` manually it doesnt work because i think that typing it only sets the `combobox1.text` value and not the `combobox1.selecteditem`. I can type a value present in the dropdown, or one not present. If i type one that is present, then the selectedItem property should also be set to the proper value. can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

solved this way:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Keyup(sender As Object, 
  e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp

      ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.FindStringExact(ComboBox1.Text)

End Sub
```