# WinForms ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to mark one of the combobox items as selected.

So I am building my combobox like this:

```
var drop = new Dictionary<int, string>();
while (RegReader.Read())
{
    drop.Add(Convert.ToInt32(RegReader["intRulesID"]), RegReader["txtName"].ToString());
}

RegRuleDrop.DataSource = new BindingSource(drop, null);
RegRuleDrop.DisplayMember = "Value";
RegRuleDrop.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Now, one of the items within the RegRuleDrop should be pre selected based on a value from a reader above this code.
Now, the problem is that I need to select value based on the actual ListItem VALUE and not TEXT.

So as an example

```
drop.Add(1, "Test");
drop.Add(2, "Test2");
drop.Add(3, "Test3");
```

I need to find the index using 1,2 or 3 not Test, Test2 or Test3

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160708/how-to-find-item-by-value-combobox-in-c-sharp. Same thing you're trying to do and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786889/set-selected-item-in-combobox-vb-net

Comment: Not quite, all of the examples there are searching by DisplayMember when I need to perform search by ValueMember :(

Comment: Why do you need to search in the first place? If you want `id=2` to be selected, just save the index of the last item in the box after adding that item in the loop.

Comment: Setting the SelectedValue property should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the DataSource set to a BindingSource the only action needed to select an item given a value belonging to the ValueMember property is

```
drop.Add(1, "Test1");
drop.Add(2, "Test2");
drop.Add(99, "Test99");
drop.Add(3, "Test3");
.....

RegRuleDrop.SelectedValue = 99
```

Comment: Awesome, Couldn't get any more easier :) Thanks
Will approve answer in 3 minutes (Limitation... :( )